# Rx Extensions flush remaining items in Buffered observable

Tags: c#, system.reactive

So I have this code:

```
ISubject<int> _processed = new ReplaySubject<int>();
_processed.Buffer(5000).Subscribe(UpdateProcessed);

// Start some process which calls _processed.OnNext
```

The problem I have is that sometimes the buffer doesnt fill, because the last batch is less than 5000 and the process exits without the call to `UpdateProcessed` being executed.

Is there a way to flush the remaining items in the `_processed` observable after the processing is complete?

Comment: Presently you must have a loop in the code that processes 5000 at a time.  After the loop you must add code to process the remain items items.  What code do you use to exit the loop?

Comment: Call `_processed.OnCompleted();` after the last call to `_processed.OnNext` (when you are done publishing items to the subject)

Comment: the loop processes 1 by 1, it´s a foreach loop over a collection with arbitrary size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OnComplete` will flush the buffers.

Try `_processed.OnComplete();`

If you do not know when the process will complete, you can always add a time span to buffer. It will emit items when either the time span expires or when the buffer is full, whichever one comes first.

`_processed.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 5000).Subscribe(UpdateProcessed);`